# Any global reporting format to show the JMeter performance result?

Tags: jmeter, reporting

I am not able to show the report to the management team in proper format. if you guys have any standared format or global format then please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) is basically a [CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) containing Sampler start time, elapsed time, connect time, whether it was successful or not, and so on, the columns can be chosen via [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

So you need to ask your management what form of "report" do they expect and generate tables and charts they're looking for.

Some options you can use fully or partially:

1. [JMeter Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) which can read the .jtl file, do some calculations/plotting and save the output in form of CSV or PNG files
2. [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) which does the same but provides possibility of automation and some extra charts on top
3. [Graphs Generator Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/GraphsGeneratorListener/)
4. It's possible to generate HTML Reporting Dashboard out of the .jtl results file
5. There is [BlazeMeter Uploader plugin](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/sense-uploader/BlazeMeterUploader.md) (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)) which uploads your test results to BlazeMeter and you can export a management-friendly report from there

   [image]
6. And last but not the least you can use [MS Excel](https://office.live.com/start/Excel.aspx) or equivalent to produce whatever output you want